# Flutter call builder function from a normal function

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc

I basically want to call my event reducer from the view. Here is my view code -

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {

  /// When user pressed get data button
  getData() async {
    print("Entering Get Data");
    Builder(builder: (context) {
      print("Inside the builder");
      // ignore: close_sinks
      final homeEventReducer = BlocProvider.of<HomeEventReducer>(context);
      homeEventReducer.add(DataRequested());
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  onPressed: getData,
                  child: new Text("Get Data"),
                ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what my `HomeEventReducer` code looks like -

```
Stream<HomeState> _reduceDataRequestedEventToState(
      DataRequested event) async* {
    yield Loading();
    try {
      final data = await _useCase.getData();
      if (data != null) {
        yield DataReceivedStatus(message: data);
      } else {
        yield DataReceivedError(message: "Data Retrieval Error");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      yield DataReceivedError(message: error.message);
    }
  }
```

I have 2 questions -

1. Inside my `HomeView`, the control flow is not getting inside the `Builder` i.e I don't get the log `print("Inside the builder");`
2. The `DataReceivedStatus` in the HomeEventReducer returns the data which I need to access in the view. How do I do it?

I am new to Flutter. Any help would be really appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

`Builder` is a widget. You are creating an instance of it when you call its constructor as `Builder(...`. You are supposed to give that instance to another widget as a child. You are not doing that. That instance of builder is going to waste, just like the sum is going to waste in the below code:

```
1 + 1; // 2 is going to waste
a = 1 + 1; // 2 is not going to waste
```

I think you want the builder to be activated when the button is pressed. In that case, your code can be like this:

```
  bool isDataRequested = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                isDataRequested != true ? new RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  onPressed:() => setState(() => isDataRequested = true;),
                  child: new Text("Get Data"),
                ) : Builder(
                  builder: // Place the builder code in here
                ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

A friendly word of advice: "I'm new to Flutter" and "I'd like to use BLoC" are two sentences that don't go well together. I'd suggest using a simpler approach to state management by using `setState()` directly, at least until you get a better hang of Flutter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but onPressed() nothing happens i.e the builder code that is supposed to be calling the HomeEventReducer is not calling

Comment: The CircularProgressIndicator does not appear?

Comment: On Press of Get Data button, I expect the builder code to be called but nothing happens

Comment: If I could get a yes/no to my question I could continue. There are many layers to what you want, you have to go step by step to find where the problem is.

Comment: Ok...The CircularProgressIndicator does not appear

Comment: It should. In that case you should share your code. Maybe you did not place Builder like I said but called getData() there, which does not return anything.